# How can I programmatically bind this CheckBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, checkbox, binding

This code is in my class constructor:

```
CheckBox autoScrollCheckBox = new CheckBox();
autoScrollCheckBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
autoScrollCheckBox.Content = "Enable";
Binding autoScrollBinding = new Binding();
autoScrollBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("AutoScrollingIsEnabled");
autoScrollBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
autoScrollBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
autoScrollCheckBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, autoScrollBinding);
autoScrollBox.Content = autoScrollCheckBox;
```

This is in the same class:

```
public bool AutoScrollingIsEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return !autoScrollingIsPaused;
    }
    set
    {
        autoScrollingIsPaused = !value;
    }
}
```

But AutoScrollingIsEnabled is never called. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I've found that the output window is extremely helpful for binding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not Relative source.

```
autoScrollBinding.Source = this;
```

But if you want an update from code to get reflected on your window then you'll need to implement INotifyProertyChanged as @evanb mentioned.